# Will iPhone modem and cellular radio turn off if WiFi connected

Tags: iphone, power-management, modem, signal-strength

Imagine an iPhone on a high speed train: the radio will burn extra power to find good signal, while transiting through poor service areas.

If I connect the iPhone to the train’s WiFi, does the iPhone power down or at least throttle-back the radio in poor service area?

Comment: This would seem counter-productive… what if someone rings you?

Comment: If you have Wi-Fi calling, then the phone likely won't try to find a cell tower.